# Install Azure IoT Edge on Debian9

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I'm going to install Azure IoT Edge along a procedure of URL in the following, 
but an error goes out and doesn't advance it first. 
Could you tell me the cause and a plan to avoid?

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux

**Linux Debian9 (kernel 4.9)**

```
root# apt-get install iotedge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iotedge : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1918

Answer (score 0):

See [Install IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-symmetric?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=azure-portal#install-iot-edge):

```
curl --insecure https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
mv ./microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
curl --insecure https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/stretch/multiarch/prod.list > ./microsoft-prod.list
mv ./microsoft-prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
apt update

apt install aziot-edge
```